# Ant don't start war target

Tags: java, ant, war

I have three targets in build.xml.

There are not errors in process.

First two runned successfully, but third don't start and there are not war file in result.

This is my buid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="LoginProject" basedir="." default="compile">

    <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="build/classes"/>
    <property name="war.dir" value="build/war"/>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath location="lib/myfaces-api-2.0.2.jar"/> 
            <classpath location="lib/servlet-api.jar"/> 
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="war" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${war.dir}"/>
        <war destfile="${war.dir}/loginproject.war" webxml="web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="WebContent"/>
            <lib dir="lib"/>
            <classes dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        </war>
    </target>   
</project>
```

And this is log from command line

```
D:\Work\Java\AntLoginProject>ant
Buildfile: D:\Work\Java\AntLoginProject\build.xml

clean:
[delete] Deleting directory D:\Work\Java\AntLoginProject\build

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Work\Java\AntLoginProject\build\classes
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to D:\Work\Java\AntLoginProject\build\classes

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

What wrong i do?

I change default target to war.
But now get error.

```
D:\Work\Java\AntLoginProject>ant war
Buildfile: D:\Work\Java\AntLoginProject\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
D:\Work\Java\AntLoginProject\build.xml:30: Content is not allowed in trailing section.

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: "war target"... sounds scary :):):)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight and also ant war ! Watch out for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the build as follows:

```
ant war
```

Alternatively change the default target from "compile" to "war"

---

**Update:**

The default target is changed as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="LoginProject" basedir="." default="war">
..
```

Comment: change the default target from "compile" to "war" gave error:                                                                                                       build.xml:30: Content is not allowed in trailing section

Comment: @savva That sounds like an invalid XML message. Are you sure you updated the correct part of the file? I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Your default target is `compile` and you only call `ant`. You need to specify `ant targetName` if you want to run a target that's not default. In your case: `ant war`.